# Как выполнить сегментацию изображения по цвету?

Tags: c++, opencv, сегментация

Имеется изображение, по видимому тряпки, содержащее набор полосок в оттенках зелёного цвета:

[image: Исходное изображение]

Значения цветов пикселей близко расположены друг к другу, плюс присутствует цветовая неоднородность в каждой из полосок, что сильно мешает, если пытаться использовать обычную бинаризацию.

Как определить область каждой из полосок на изображении?

Comment: С OpenCV не работал, но вроде бы надо размыть, набросать кучу точек и найти из них цветовые кластеры.

Comment: нужен алгоритм - фильтр типа smar tblur. Это размытие с порогом. Пороги бывают разные по величине фильтра по силе цветового перепада, по яркости. Надо убить тонкие белые полоски сохранив темные вертикальные, а дальше уже кластеризовать...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Время, затраченное на поиск решения, показало, что с авторами комментариев об использовании размытия и кластеризации трудно не согласиться. Обнаружил, что для реализации второго пункта (собственно, кластеризации) можно воспользоваться методом K-средних. Конечно при условии, что заранее известно количество цветных полос на изображении:

```
const int cluster_count = 10;
```

Загружаем изображение из файла и разбиваем его матрицу на отдельные каналы:

```
cv::Mat src_mat = cv::imread("image.jpg");
if(src_mat.empty()) return;

std::vector<cv::Mat> channels;
cv::split(src_mat, channels);
```

По умолчанию OpenCV загрузит картинку в `BGR` формате. Можно произвести её конвертацию в другие цветовые пространства (например, `HSV` или `YCbCr`), но от этого в дальнейшем не случилось какой-либо выгоды. Пробовал даже комбинировать разные каналы разных цветовых пространств между собой, но и это улучшения также не дало.

Далее необходимо создать матрицу, высота которой будет равна количеству точек исходного изображения, а ширина - количеству каналов, полученных ранее:

```
const int rows = src_mat.rows * src_mat.cols;
const int cols = channels.size();

cv::Mat mat = cv::Mat::zeros(rows, cols, CV_8U);
for(int col = 0; col < cols; ++col) {
    // Применяем размытие с ядром 4х4.
    // Как оказалось, это даёт самый лучший результат.
    // Больший размер ядра фильтра размытия ведёт
    // к большей деформации результата, так что 4х4 - это компромисс.
    cv::Mat blr_mat;
    cv::blur(channels[col], blr_mat, cv::Size(4,4));

    // Размытое изображение переформатируем в матрицу с одной колонкой.
    blr_mat.reshape(1,rows).copyTo(mat.col(col));
}
```

Конвертируем данные матрицы в тип числа с плавающей точкой - float:

```
mat.convertTo(mat, CV_32F);
```

Остаётся сама кластеризация методом K-средних:

```
cv::Mat labels_mat;
cv::kmeans(mat, cluster_count, labels_mat, cv::TermCriteria(), 1
    , cv::KMEANS_PP_CENTERS);
```

Теперь `labels_mat` будет содержать значения принадлежности каждого пикселя изображения тому или иному кластеру. Для удобства рисования, можно эти значения нормализовать:

```
cv::convertScaleAbs(labels_mat.reshape(0,src_mat.rows)
    , labels_mat, 255/cluster_count, 1);
```

Полученный результат:

[image: Результат]

Заметно, что всё далеко не идеально, однако в целом цветовые полоски выделены правильно и просто требуется поработать над ликвидацией артефактов. Это уже можно осуществить при помощи морфологических операций или даже через обработку контурами, отсеяв мелкие по их площади.